# Underscore.js "some" not return boolean

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js, backbone-layout-manager

I'm using underscore.js to check if an element is true within a list. Here is the coffeescript code for it:

```
uploading  = _(@getViews ".file-forms").some (view) ->
    view.uploading is true
```

printing 'uploading', instead of returning true or false, gives:

```
uploading
  y
   _chain: true
   _wrapped: false
   __proto__: Object
```

Here is the definition of 'some' for underscore: http://underscorejs.org/#some.

In addition, getViews is a function from backbone layoutmanager defined here: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Nested-views

Here is the output of other variables that might make this easier to debug:

```
_(this.getViews(".file-forms"))
 y
  _chain: true
  _wrapped: Array[1]
  0: d
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
  __proto__: Object

_
 function (a){if(a instanceof y)return a;if(this instanceof y)this._wrapped=a;else return new y(a)}
```

Comment: Can you show your output javascript? Looks like it's calling `chain()` without `value()`

Comment: I print it with console.log(uploading) (with output as shown above). By 'output javascript' do you mean the javascript produced by compiling the coffeescript? You can see it by just copy pasting the coffeescript here: http://coffeescript.org/ under "Try Coffeescript"

Comment: In javascript/underscore it works fine. You have either a coffeescript or backbone problem. Can you show the results of `getViews` and of the literal `_` in your environment?

Comment: Yup, added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [`getViews`](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/backbone.layoutmanager.js#L89), you'll see what's going on:

```
getViews: function(fn) {
  //...
  if (typeof fn === "string") {
    return _.chain([this.views[fn]]).flatten();
  }
  //...
}
```

If you look at all the possible return values, you'll see that they're all the result of [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) calls without a [`_.value`](http://underscorejs.org/#value) call to peel off the chaining wrapper. That means that `getViews` is returning a chainable Underscore wrapper, not the simple array you're expecting.

You shouldn't be doing `_(@getViews '...')` since the `getViews` return value is already wrapped in Underscore. You should be able to do something like this instead:

```
uploading = @getViews(".file-forms").some((view) -> view.uploading is true).value()
```

---

As an aside, I'm a little suspicious of your `v.uploading is true` test; explicit checks against `true` and `false` can cause odd behavior (especially in CoffeeScript where `is` is really `===`). I'd probably use `(v) -> v.uploading` as the function instead. Of course, this is personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

`getViews` seems to be returning a pre-wrapped, and chained, underscore object for your consumption. Calling `_` on it again does nothing in this circumstance. You can put `uploading.value()` to get the result you want.